# What's the fastest WinForms controls suite (commercial)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

My employer wants to sell "sexy" applications which means they don't really want the standard controls of Windows to be used. I do, because of the better performance, but they pay so they decide. Currently I'm using the latest version of Telerik WinForms. They all may look great but the performance is very very disappointing ...

F.e.: I created just a simple empty WinForm project with just one Form without anything else (no controls added and no code). Without Telerik it takes < 1 second to load; *with* Telerik it takes 3-4 seconds, and I have a modern/fast PC ...

To be clear: it's not only the initial loading that's slow. The overall performance is also slower than I desire.

I know that using fancy controls means you have to sacrifice speed. But so much?

So, my question is: are there any (commercial) control packages that perform better? This is what it must provide at least:

- Office 2007 look (colors and form).
- Ribbon.
- Docking control.

NB: Price must be around the same price as Telerik (< $900).

Update: sorry to see my question closed as being not constructive/suitable. Don't agree with it as I see the perfomance issue as a problem that could be solved by a better controls suite.

Comment: have you looked at Infragistics?

Comment: @0A0D: Not yet, I'm currently started looking at DXperience. Is it faster that you know of then?

Comment: I've not tried it lately, but they do make some good looking controls.

Comment: I second the "performance is disappointing" bit with Telerik -- at least during the initial "preparation" (it would be nice if this was amortizable). There is also ComponentOne as another provider in this market (DevExpress was already mentioned) but I have no experience with either.

Comment: Don't know what I got a -1 vote. Don't think it's a strange question (who doesn't care for performance) and didn't found a similar question here yet (until now).

Comment: @0A0D: Don't care for the looks much. Just want speed with something that looks good enough.

Comment: check them out: http://www.infragistics.com/

Comment: @0A0D: Just saw it costs $1300; a bit too pricy for us.

Comment: Have you tried WPF controls, default or any from the aforementioned providers?

Comment: Also very interested in the answer; we use DXperience so far and are using it more rather than less and wonder what will happen to our performance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Krypton](http://www.componentfactory.com/product?id=3) controls, they are very pretty and have excellent constancy through out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; my first test projects with it seems to be a faster result so far. I would have additional question about it, but unfortunately my question is closed ... :(

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't see such huge delays. Yes, the styling of Telerik's controls has some impact on the initial form loading, but not as much... Which version of Telerik's tools have you tried?

I did a quick test with their latest version (Q2 2011) and I was not able to see such delays. The test was done on a fairly quick PC (Intel Core2 Quad CPU Q9400 @ 2.66 GHz; RAM: 8.00 GB). See quick video here (the times are in milliseconds): http://screencast.com/t/4I8Q536Np

Have you contacted Telerik Support about this? If not, please do so - they will be happy to check this for you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I use DotNetBar from DevComponents which I've found pretty good. They have all the elements you say you're looking for and they are cheaper than most of the others ($264 for single developer):

http://www.devcomponents.com/

I've also used [Nevron UI](http://www.nevron.com/Products.UserInterfaceFor.NET.Overview.aspx) in the past, but I'd say that DotNetBar has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the [Codejock control suite](http://www.codejock.com/) to develop a new interface for our product. I haven't tried the .NET versions in my apps but I have run the .NET code sample and there seems to be no performance issue.

They include a ribbon control theming and docking among many more.

The learning curve is moderate for the ribbon control but once you get into it you get up and running and the provided samples are very good.

Pricing seems very competitive as well so I can't recommend them enough. - and no I don't work for them!

Comment: Codejock seems to be for Visual C++... I think @marcus-v needs solution for Visual C#

Comment: @Harsh - the controls are COM components but fully supported in .NET with samples in both VB.NET and C# - "Codejock is a leading provider of components and controls for Visual C++ MFC, ActiveX COM and .NET WinForm technologies."